# How to use qml camera in js file?

Tags: javascript, qml

I want to capture images in new thread because this process freezes main GUI. How can I make new thread to use qml camera in Javascript to avoid freezing of main interface?

```
//main.qml MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: 
    myWorker.sendMessage("Capture Image")
}
WorkerScript
{
        id: myWorker
        source: "qrc:/images/threader.js"  
        onMessage:console.log("Captured") 
 }      //threader.js WorkerScript.onMessage=function(message) { 
        WorkerScript.sendMessage({'reply': camera.ImageCapture.Capture()}) }
```

Comment: My guess would be that you capture the image like always, i.e. in the main/GUI thread, and then pass it to the worker for processing

Comment: How can I send this image to worker?

Comment: In QML/JavaScript with `sendMessage()`. Might make sense to consider doing the image processing in C++ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML is not really designed with the intention of working within more than one thread. The origional intention was that any threading should be handled by the layer existing in C++. Check this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html) for an example for capturing images in C++.